# Integer is Incompatible with UniqueIdentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

This is my code:

```
USE [MRC]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Lookup_APN_GUID] 
(
      -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @PN_Key int
)
RETURNS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
      -- Declare the return variable here
      DECLARE @PN_GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

      SELECT @PN_GUID = PNID
      FROM PNEB
      WHERE PNID = (@PN_Key)

      RETURN @PN_GUID
END
```

I get the following error message:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2
>   Procedure Lookup_PN_GUID, Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

I tried switching `int` to `nvarchar` on the scalar variable declaration. Still get error message.  The `uniqueidentifier` is an `int`. I'm at a loss.

Any Ideas?

Comment: The `select` seems to be assuming that `PNID` is a `uniqueidentifier`.  The `where` clause is saying it is an `int`.  Which is it?  Perhaps ou have to change the declaration of `@PN_KEY` to `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: You can declare that like NCHAR(50) and compare that parameter with PNID converted to NCHAR using CONVERT method

Comment: Are you sure it's `WHERE PNID = @PN_Key` and not `WHERE [SOME_OTHER_COLUMN] = @PN_Key` ? Can u post definition for table `PNEB` ?

Comment: show us the structure of `PNEB` table

Comment: Well, I recreated the function and it worked.  I don't know what happened because I used the same code.  THANKS FOR ALL YOUR INPUT

Comment: I was wrong by my last comment.  The function executed successfully but my SSIS package stated otherwise.  I was referencing the wrong attribute PNID (WHERE PNID = (@PN_Key). I will post the valid function script for future reference by users.  Thanks again for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [MRC]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Lookup_APN_GUID] 
(
      -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @PN_Key int
)
RETURNS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
      -- Declare the return variable here
      DECLARE @PN_GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
      SELECT @PN_GUID = PNID
      FROM PNEB
      **WHERE APNID = (@PN_Key)**

      RETURN @PN_GUID
END
```